# Написать функцию, которая заменяет все числа, встречающиеся в строке на наименьшее из них

Tags: c++, строки

Написала функцию, но она меняет числа посимвольно =(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void MinimizeNumbers(string &src);


int main(){


    string str;
    MinimizeNumbers(str);



    return 0;
}

void MinimizeNumbers(string &src){
    getline (cin, src);
    char min = 999999;
    for (int i= 0; i < src.length(); i++){  
      if(isdigit(src[i]) ){
        if(src[i] < min)
          min = src[i];
        src[i] = min;
      }
    }
    cout  << src;

}
```

При вводе 2 15 44 выдает 2 22 22, а нужно чтобы выдавала 2 2 2

Comment: Во входной строке будут только числа?

Comment: Нет, могут быть и буквы

Comment: более того: если вы введете  44  15  2, то ваша программа выдаст 44 11 1

Comment: Я бы использовал istringstream

Comment: @Not Bjarne Stroustrup,  эффективно использовать  istringstream для строки, например, не разделенной символом разделителем, не получится

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну я написал рабочий код. Скину в ответ. Посмотрите пожалуйста, может будут замечания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, как смог (осталось только разбить на функции):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <climits>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string input;
    cout << "Input >> ";
    getline(cin, input);

    istringstream instr(input);
    int minValue = INT_MAX;
    int currentValue;

    // Пропускаем все символы пока не встретим первую цифру
    while (instr && !isdigit(instr.peek()))
    {
        instr.get();
    }
    // Если мы не дошли до конца строки и встретили первую цифру, то читаем все число
    while (instr >> currentValue)
    {
        // Определяем меньше ли это число предыдущего и повторяем
        minValue = currentValue < minValue ? currentValue : minValue;
        while (instr && !isdigit(instr.peek()))
        {
            instr.get();
        }
    }


    istringstream inResult(input);
    string result;
    // Заносим все символы из входной строки до первого числа
    while (inResult && !isdigit(inResult.peek()))
    {
        result += inResult.get();
    }
    // Если встретили число, читаем его (что бы пропустить)
    while (inResult >> currentValue)
    {
        // а вместо него вставляем наше минимальное число и повторяем
        result += to_string(minValue);
        while (inResult && !isdigit(inResult.peek()))
        {
            result += inResult.get();
        }
    }

    // Вывод результатов
    cout << input << endl;
    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ввод >> 12  245 22
Вывод >> 12 245 22

Comment: @Nastya Так вывод для сравнения. Я в конце вывожу то что ввели и потом то что получилось. Результат лежит в result. В input лежит начальный ввод

Comment: Не заметила код ниже). Ну если полностью код запустить, то выдает ошибку в  36 и 58 строчках

Comment: @Nastya какую ошибку? У меня компилируется без ошибок

Comment: 36   error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_istringstream<char>& std::basic_istringstream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_istringstream<char>&)'

Comment: Так а как Вы написали первый комментарий если у Вас ошибка компиляции?

Comment: Скомпилировала только часть программы, дописав вывод

Comment: @Nastya отредактировал ответ. Теперь попробуйте. На cppreference посмотрел и дествительно конструктор копирования и операция присваивания удалены. А у меня компилируется без ошибок. Странно.

Comment: Смысль строкового потока, для данной задачи,  теряется, когда вы читаете посимвольно. Посимвольно можно читать  прямо в строке... Правильность кода не проверял.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Согласен. Использовал istringstream только для удобного извлечения чисел из строки

Comment: Не думаю, что  ваш код будет работать для всех случаев,  и не нужно слышком разворачиваться комментариями, поэтому просто пропущу без какой либо оценки

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А почему не для всех случаев?

Comment: не знаю мне так показалось. Я не внимательно смотрел. Сейчас проверю

Comment: Всем спасибо, очень помогли)

Answer (score 0):

Ловите страшный костыль ) Но работает как танк)

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


int main() {

    std::string line{"aa 12 2 1 123 s2 31 4 ss"};

    std::istringstream ss{line};
    std::string s;
    int min{std::numeric_limits<int>::max()};

    while(ss >> s) {
        int n{};
        std::istringstream iss (s);
        iss >> n;
        if (iss.fail()) {
            continue;
        }
        min = std::min(min, n);
    }

    std::istringstream ss2{line};
    std::string s2;

    while(ss2 >> s2) {
        int n{};
        std::istringstream iss (s2);
        iss >> n;
        if (iss.fail()) {
            std::cout << s2 << " ";
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << min << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;


    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Мой костыль страшнее))) А Ваш костыль заменяет несколько подряд идущих пробелов одним

Comment: О каких вы проделах говорите ? Где вы их нашли ?

Comment: Ну если в строке будет несколько пробелов подряд, то Ваш алгоритм оставит только один из них

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup да хоть их 500 будет подряд, их опустят, прочитайте про istringstream. Я вообще в шоке с чего вы сделали такой вывод

Comment: Куда опустят? Я говорю что Ваш алгоритм превращает строку `"aa 12          2 1 123 4s2 31 4 ss"` в `"aa 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ss"` + если где-то будет 2 или больше пробела подряд, то Ваш алгоритм заменит эти пробелы одним пробелом

Comment: Вы тролите? От возьмите Ваш ответ и вставте в строку между aa и 12 пять пробелов. В результате между aa и 12 будет только один пробел

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup ааа, вы про сохрарниеие исходного форматирования пробелов.... тьфу... ну я же писал костыль)